# How to convert a table-like character list into a table in R?

Tags: r

I got a report from a large function in R. It prints a table for plotting. I copied the text format output like this

```
cyl        wt       mpg        se      LLCI      ULCI
     4.0000    2.1568   27.3998    0.7199   25.9250   28.8746
     6.0000    2.1568   23.2805    0.8261   21.5882   24.9727
     8.0000    2.1568   19.1611    1.5544   15.9770   22.3452
     4.0000    3.3250   21.0658    1.2733   18.4575   23.6742
     6.0000    3.3250   18.8352    0.6544   17.4947   20.1758
     8.0000    3.3250   16.6046    0.7792   15.0084   18.2008
     4.0000    3.8436   18.2540    1.8031   14.5604   21.9476
     6.0000    3.8436   16.8619    0.8921   15.0345   18.6892
     8.0000    3.8436   15.4697    0.6120   14.2161   16.7234
```

and pasted it using `x <- readClipboard()`. Then I `summary(x)` and got

```
Length     Class      Mode 
       10 character character
```

How can I change `x` into a numeric table with headings for plotting? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe wt as x and mpg as y. Just some lines. The problem is that I don't know how to convert the text format table to a data frame. I can do it in excel and get it back to R, but it would be awesome to know how to do that in R itself.

Comment: can you please try the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to convert to a `data.frame`, an option is `soread` after copying the text (`Ctrl + C`)

```
library(overflow)
df1 <- soread()
```

The output is a `data.frame` which can be used for plotting

```
str(df1)
#'data.frame':  9 obs. of  6 variables:
# $ cyl : num  4 6 8 4 6 8 4 6 8
# $ wt  : num  2.16 2.16 2.16 3.33 3.33 ...
# $ mpg : num  27.4 23.3 19.2 21.1 18.8 ...
# $ se  : num  0.72 0.826 1.554 1.273 0.654 ...
# $ LLCI: num  25.9 21.6 16 18.5 17.5 ...
# $ ULCI: num  28.9 25 22.3 23.7 20.2 ...
```

Once, we have the `data.frame`, it can be used with `ggplot` after reshaping into 'long' format

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)    
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = rn, y = value, color = name)) +
      geom_line() +
      theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, akrun! But my rstudio told me that package ‘overflow’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2). Is there anything else I can do? Thanks!

Comment: @MC2020 you can install from [github](https://github.com/mrdwab/overflow-mrdwab) sorry should have mentioned earlier

Comment: Yeah, I just googled it and found the solution. Very nice of you for plotting that! Your answer really helps! Thank you so much.